# Issuing PRAGMA statement in AIR app

Tags: sqlite, encoding, air, pragma

When I use the flash.data routines to issue a SQLite "PRAGMA encoding" statement, I get an error suggesting that this isn't supported:

```
'Error #3115: SQL Error.', details:'PRAGMA is not allowed in SQL.', operation:'execute', detailID:'2005
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: There is a workaround for at least one simple use of PRAGMA as I described in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417131/changing-sqlite-database-encoding-in-air-app-to-utf-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word no. See for supported and unsupported features.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd47bd22bdd97276f1365b8c112629d7c47c-8000.html#WSd47bd22bdd97276f-5741a41a1262b2de46b-8000.

However on that page however you will see...
System table access is not available
    The system tables including sqlite_master and other tables with the "sqlite_" prefix are not available in SQL statements. The runtime includes a schema API that provides an object-oriented way to access schema data. For more information see the [SQLConnection.loadSchema()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLConnection.html#loadSchema%28%29) method.

For a more detailed help in using loadSchema have a look at,

http://gmarius.posterous.com/a-test-33

and consider using,

http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/ In fact

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure why you threw in all the stuff about system tables since it's unrelated to my question, but since that first linked page does include a clear statement that PRAGMA is unsupported I'll accept it anyway.

Comment: Don, cool, thanks.  Didn't clue in to that.  Basically you're using the browser to do what I did with the sqlite3 command line tool.