# Changing SQLite database encoding in AIR app to UTF-8

Tags: sqlite, encoding, utf-8, air

In an AIR app you can use SQLite via the flash.data classes.  It appears that by default the encoding of the database created is set to UTF-16le, which means that textual data is stored with two bytes per character, resulting in a nearly 100% overhead for ASCII-heavy database content.

The default for a SQLite database is UTF-8, assuming the shell program (sqlite3) is indicative.  Presumably Adobe has decided to override this for some reason, but I'd prefer not to suffer the wasted storage space if possible.

A `PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";` statement prior to writing anything to the database would normally resolve the issue, but it appears [that's not allowed in AIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417040/issuing-pragma-statement-in-air-app) either.

My workaround for now is to use a "template.db" that I create ahead of time and bundled into the application.  In this template.db I've set the encoding to UTF-8 manually.  If the database file does not exist already when my program starts, I create it by copying that template to my database file, then proceed to open and use it normally.  I've confirmed that TEXT data is then stored as UTF-8, as desired.

I haven't seen any ill effects yet, but this is hackish.  Is there a better way to set the encoding to UTF-8?  Or is it a Bad Idea for some reason?

Comment: Don't suppose you've found an answer to this question? I'm kind of in the same boat now.

Comment: Other than my workaround, no. It worked fine though, and it's used in production code.

Comment: I suggest you add your workaround as an answer and accept it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*With no other workarounds or answers found, I'm posting my workaround as the Answer. It worked fine in a PlayBook app for the last two years, so presumably has no unforeseen side-effects, at least in that environment:*

My workaround for now is to use a "template.db" that I create ahead of time and bundled into the application. In this template.db I've set the encoding to UTF-8 manually. If the database file does not exist already when my program starts, I create it by copying that template to my database file, then proceed to open and use it normally. I've confirmed that TEXT data then now stored as UTF-8 as desired.

Answer (score 0):

you may check the execution source file of the project  like /bin/debug in C# Visual Studio projects.

The changed committed is not necessarily be executed in your db located in other folders.